# Do the deities punish those people who have cursed them?

Tags: gods

Out of anger , if a person who is a normal and simple devotee of god, curses them and use very offensive and vulgar language, then do the deities punish them ?
If the devotee sincerely asks for forgiveness , will he/she forgive the devotee?

Comment: Brahmavaivarta Purana states that in each hair-pit of God lies a brahmanda (endowed with the 14 realms beginning from Brahmaloka to Rasatala). To think that God would get perturbed by the foul language of a single human in a single Bhuloka in a single brahmanda is nothing but human ego.

Comment: See , the person curses god when he really becomes helpless, but again devotedly asks for forgiveness , so will he / she be forgiven ?

Comment: @SoumyadipDas  Bhagavad Gita 9.30
Even if the vilest sinners worship Me with exclusive devotion, they are to be considered righteous because they have made the proper resolve.  ;so  I think forgiven but true devotion you must never do again. Actually I don't know/remember any verse where it talks about people cursing God.